# How to limit Google search result to a set of websites?

Tags: google-search, mobile, opera

I want to limit my Google search query to a set of websites. I am using the Opera Mini browser on my tablet for searching.

Comment: You can use advanced search techniques in Google. Something like "someword:www.website.com". This will search the specific site for the word(s) you provide. Never tried running this against multiple sites.

Answer (score 30):

You're already likely familiar with using `site:superuser.com` to limit your query to a single website. For example, typing this into the Google search box limits your search to **superuser.com**:

```
reboot site:superuser.com
```

Now, you can use the `OR` operator to add another site to your query:

```
reboot site:superuser.com OR site:android.stackexchange.com
```

You can try the above searches with these links:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=reboot%20site:superuser.com
- https://www.google.com/search?q=reboot%20site:superuser.com%20OR%20site:android.stackexchange.com

Bookmark the resulting link after changing them to your websites of choice, so you can run other searches later without having to type everything again on your tablet.

Comment: note the capitals in `OR`; it won't work when using `or`.

Comment: Unfortunately seems stopped working in 2019

Answer (score 4):

You can use existing search engines. Most provide a keyword limiting search results to one/more sites. For example, on google, you can use the `site:` keyword, along with `OR` or `AND`:

`Android AND site:engadget.com OR site:gizmodo.com OR site:betanews.com` etc.

Comment: epic. just epic.

Comment: So like using google?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a Google Custom Search Engine, if this is a collection of sites that you want to run a restricted search on - and is worth doing if you want to search the same site-collection more than once.

Google's instructions on how to do this are here:   https://support.google.com/customsearch/?hl=en#topic=4513742

To actually use the engine yourself, you need to put it into a website somewhere.    I've put one into Blogger a number of times - either as an HTML/Javascript gadget, or even in a post (by switching into HTML mode, and pasting in the code).

It's been a while since I did this, but last time I wrote up the process [here](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2010/10/putting-custom-search-engine-in-your.html) - I don't think that the process has changed much since then.

Answer (score 1):

If you include `site:` in your query, Google will restrict your search results to the site or domain you specify. For example, [ `admissions site:www.lse.ac.uk` ] will show admissions information from London School of Economics’ site and [ `peace site:gov` ] will find pages about peace within the `.gov` domain. You can specify a domain with or without a period, e.g., either as `.gov` or `gov`.

Note: Do not include a space between the “`site:`” and the domain.

You can use many of the search operators in conjunction with the basic search operators `+`, `–`, `OR`, and `" "`. For example, to find information on Windows security from all sites except `microsoft.com`, enter: [`windows security –site:microsoft.com`]

You can also restrict your results to a site or domain through the domains selector on the Advanced Search page.

Source: [Google Search Operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html)