# How can I google search a defined set of domains/sites for a certain string

Tags: google-search

I want to search for a string and limit that search to certain sites.

For instance I may want to search

```
Google TV site:walmart.com
Google TV site:amazon.com
Google TV site:bn.com
Google TV site:bestbuy.com
Google TV site:toysrus.com
```

I want to be able to type in the string each time, but limit the search to those domains, it's ok if each are in a seperate window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it appears to work. Type in the search field.

> (site:wikipedia.com OR site:apple.com) yosemite

Comment: That's the one-off solution.    For a repeatable solution, see  "How to limit Google search result to a set of websites" - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70005/how-to-limit-google-search-result-to-a-set-of-websites